# QRegularExpression matching thread safety

Tags: c++, qt, thread-safety

Can I use Qt `QRegularExpression` safely in multiple threads without locking? The regex object will be declared global `const` and I will use only `const` member functions.

Comment: I don't think you need to ask the same thing over and over again. Nothing in Qt is thread-safe unless it's explicitly mentioned to be so.

Comment: @KubaOber Containers are said to be read-only thread-safe, why not regular expressions? I asked only to check this. PCRE seems to be thread safe when matching compiled regex in different threads and QRegularExpression is based on it.

Comment: The read-only thread safety is a mirage that makes it too easy to slip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single, explicitly-shared instance of `QRegularExpression` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. If all you are calling on it is `const` member functions they you might be OK, but there is no guarantee. The only documented guarantee is that two different instances can be used in two different threads without locking, i.e. any data which is implicitly shared between instances is internally synchronized.

However, `QRegularExpression` is one of Qt's [implicitly shared classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), which means that copying an instance of `QRegularExpression` is extremely cheap, because the copy will *share* the data of the original, and the actual data will only be copied if one of the instances is modified (copy-on-write). And the [shared data itself is thread-safe](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-implicitly-shared-classes).

So the really safe (and efficient) way would be to make a local copy of the global `QRegularExpression` in each thread:

```
QRegularExpression globalRegex("[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*");

void thread1() {
    auto localRegex = globalRegex;
    // do something with localRegex
}

void thread2() {
    auto localRegex = globalRegex;
    // do something with localRegex
}
```

The only case in which the shared data would be copied would be if one of the local regex objects were to be modified, in which case a single global regex object would not have been thread-safe anyway. If you really want a single global `QRegularExpression` object shared between threads then a lock would be advisable.

Comment: I solved it by marking the global variable `thread_local`. Is this safe?

Comment: @Nazar554 It is safe, but not as efficient. Each thread will recreate a separate regex from scratch when the thread starts.

Comment: With my "QRegularExpression author" hat, I can tell you that QRegularExpression is actually thread safe, as long as you only use const methods). But if you rely on that I'm going to give you a bad time. :-) The documented warranty is that it's reentrant, i.e. at most one thread touches a given QRegularExpression instance at any time; locking must happen externally if 2 or more threads want to use the same instance.

Comment: Note that this also implies that the example above is wrong -- two threads are reading from the same instance without locking. You should first copy, then start the thread (giving it the copy).

Comment: @Oktalist shared data itself is `not` thread-safe between threads, you are wrong! documentation says `Proper locking should be used when sharing an instance of an implicitly shared class between threads.`

Comment: @RezaEbrahimi "Shared data itself" and "instance of implicitly shared class" are two different things. _You_ are wrong. That quote just repeats the first line of my answer.

Comment: @Oktalist Yes, I'm understand the difference between instance and shared memory block, a instance of implicitly shared class have one data member that points to shared data block, the pointer itself is not protected, any copying of the instances just create a pointer and increment ref count as an atomic operation, but what happens when you access to shared data pointer from two or more threads? is that protected?

Comment: @RezaEbrahimi The shared data is protected, as explained in my answer and the documentation you quoted from. We agree that the shared data _pointer_ (data member of the instance) is not protected, but _points to_ the protected shared data.

Comment: @peppe If we were talking about `QString`, would the save caveat apply?

Comment: @Oktalist: in general, it applies to all implicitly-shared classes: they're all reentrant, not thread safe. (Always refer to the docs to know the status of each class!) Their const API is *usually* thread safe, and we're trying to actually make it so everywhere and document it (maybe in Qt 6). But please be careful not to over-rely on that; there is the usual function here and there that will stab you in the back. For QString, the usual gem is the `utf16()` function: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp.html#_ZNK7QString5utf16Ev

Comment: In my experience using implicitly shared copies of QRegularExpression results in far worse performance than creating independent instances for each thread. Probably, because of some kind of internal synchronization when shared data is accessed.